# TO_DATE and then use in the WHERE with a BETWEEN

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Can I take this SELECT below, substr out the 24 hour fallacy and replace it with 00 hour and then run the WHERE TRUNC(TO_DATE(FIX_DATETIME, 'MMDDYYHH24MISS')) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-90) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE)?  Can it be done in one pass? If so,whether on pass or more, how?  You help is very much appreciated and your skill levels are respected.

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID,
    (CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 7, 2) = '24' THEN SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 1, 2)||SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 3, 2)||SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 5, 2)||'00'||SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 9, 2)||SUBSTR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 11, 2)
        ELSE MOPACTIVITY.MOPID
    END ) FIX_DATETIME,
sysdate "SYSDATE"
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a varchar column? That is a sure way of getting into trouble.

Comment: Big company database.  I have requested the change but it isn't gonna happen.  That I why I am trying to work around it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The *only* sensible solution is to change the column to a proper `DATE` column. Everything else is just a hack.

Comment: I hear and agree with you but the change isn't going to happen.  The database isn't going to change, so I have to hack it.  I believe I have presented the issue to the higher ups but I am shouting at the wind. :(  No ideas how to hack around it?

Answer (score 5):

Leaving aside for a moment the incongruity of a column named `MOPID` which someone would naturally assume to be some sort of numeric ID is actually a `VARCHAR2` that happens to represent a `DATE` and the fact that you should never store a `DATE` as a `VARCHAR2` because you will inevitably end up with invalid data in that column that will cause queries to start throwing errors seemingly at random when query plans change...

```
WHERE to_date(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 'MMDDYYHH24MISS') BETWEEN (sysdate-90) and sysdate
```

would do what you seem to want.

To identify the rows that have invalid data (almost certain when you use the wrong data type)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_valid_date( p_str IN VARCHAR2,
                                          p_mask IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_dt  DATE;
BEGIN
  l_dt := to_date( p_str, p_mask );
  RETURN 'Y';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN 'N';
END;
```

and then

```
SELECT *
  FROM MOPACTIVITY
 WHERE is_valid_date( MOPID, 'MMDDYYHH24MISS' ) = 'N'
```

You can try to find invalid data using regular expressions or by trying to `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` various components.  That approach, however, can only ever be approximate unless you want to try to implement every possible calendar rule (i.e. 29-31 is a valid day in some months and some years but not others).  It's generally easier to simply let `to_date` try the conversion and to rely on Oracle to implement all those rules.

Comment: I like your intro :-). I'd assume that `sysdate - 90` implies the OP wants 3 months ago as well, which implies `ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, -3)` _might_ be what they're actually after.

Comment: I whole heartedly agree with you on how the MOPID field is setup, but I have inherited this mess.  I have tried the same code you suggested but I get an Error: ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23.  What causes that and how do I get around it?

Comment: That probably means you have invalid data, as forecast. You can find the bad value using a query like `SELECT MOPID FROM myTable WHERE SUBSTR(MOPID, 7, 2) NOT BETWEEN '00' AND '23'`.

Comment: @EdGibbs, that is at the heart of the issue for sure!  I am still smacking my head against the wall trying to get a solution.  You have moved me one step closer. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If you need to dive in and find bad values, probably the first thing would be to make sure that the column at least has exactly 12 digits. You can find columns that aren't exactly 12 digits with `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(MOPID, '^\d{12}$')`. Once you've gotten anything that isn't all digits fixed you can start doing some numeric comparisons to make sure the month is between 1 and 12, the hour is between 0 and 23, etc. Good luck - I've inherited plenty of lousy databases so I feel your pain :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for *date* comparisons, you should use:

```
WHERE to_date(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 'MMDDYYHH24MISS') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate-90) and trunc(sysdate)
```

or

```
WHERE to_date(substr(MOPACTIVITY.MOPID, 1, 6), 'MMDDYY') BETWEEN trunc(sysdate-90) and trunc(sysdate)
```

This assumes that you want complete days, including the current day (which is partial up to the current time) and the first day from midnight (not the current time).

Comment: Error: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: So my where looks like this

Comment: So there really isn't a way to strip that varchar2 field to just mm/dd/yyyy format to be use in a BETWEEN in the WHERE of the sql?  I understand this is the correct field type but that is out of my control. :(

Comment: @CorpaLoom . . . I guess I just don't store date/time fields in character strings.  In any case, I modified the answer to show two different ways of doing it.

Comment: ...I truly appreciate all of your help!